# mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem, Please Help me. I'm using Code igniter
This is my code.

my Models (M_register.php)

```
class M_register extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function add_account($data)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->insert('login',$data);           
        **return  mysqli_insert_id();**
    }

    function changeActiveState($key)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $data = array(
           'active' => 1
        );

        $this->db->where('md5(id)', $key);
        $this->db->update('login', $data);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is partly code in Controller
$data = array(

```
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'nama' => $nama,
        'email' => $email,
        'active' => 0
    );
    $this->load->model('m_register');
    **$id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);**        
    $encrypted_id = md5($id);
enter code here
```

And this My error:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is clear :
**mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given**

You must give it the connection in parameter. For example :

```php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName,LastName,Age) VALUES ('Glenn','Quagmire',33)");

// Here the call to "mysqli_insert_id" takes the output of "mysqli_connect" as parameter
echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($con); 

mysqli_close($con);
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

I don't know in your code where you're doing the connection, but check that your call to `$this->load->database()` doesn't return the connection resource.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the database connection variable as parameter

```
$query = $this->db->insert('login',$data);
return  mysqli_insert_id($dbconnection);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using codeigniter, so it would be better if you use codeigniter functions only to perform database operation.

Definitely you will get result using mysqli_insert_id(db_connection_object)
But it would be better if you use inbuilt function of codeigniter

```
    $this->db->insert_id();
```